# Control font size in creation of template wizard

Tags: font-sizes

I'm trying to propose another UX/UI way to display a control font size in a wizard of templates creation.

[image]

Have you a UX advice about my choice? I think that it must have a more precise mark of font size. Could you give an expert advice ?

Comment: Can you describe in a bit more detail how this control works? Just how gradual does the slider change the size - just in 2 increments smaller / larger? What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve that a traditional font size control doesn't offer?

Comment: Hi @JonW, The left side serves as a preview. On the right side, I provide a option to select the typeface and choice the fontsize. I wanted to propose a different size control : a incremental bar with 5 states. Is it a good UX choice?

Comment: This is a standard problem, I would guess, and has been solved (i.e., designed) in many applications which do similar stuff to the app you're working on. Did you do some research on these other applications? We appreciate you showing you also did some homework :-)

Comment: I think that my proposal for control font size missing of values, I give the options to choice "a size" (5 increments) without a real value. I would like to have senior advices about my proposal :)

Answer (score 1):

You could call your first dropdown "Font Family" - selecting a font from a dropdown is a pretty standard pattern, so you're okay there.

For font size, it depends on how much detail your user needs. Again, you could use a dropdown, with arbitrary values like "Extra Small, Small, Medium, Large, Extra Large" and this might suffice for novice users or those who likely wouldn't care about font size.

If your user does care, you might want to give control over the size of each hierarchical element. Here's an example from BeaverBuilder:

[image: BeaverBuilder font size configuration using several sliders]

The size shows in a text input field next to a slider, and can be reset.

What's nice about this is that the user can enter arbitrary values if they want to, but the example on the right helps them understand how big something will appear if they're not into values.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that the image on the left is the feedback mechanism for the selections made on the right - i.e. it shows a selection of styles based on the selected font.

The feedback mechanism
I think it is confusing to have the primary and secondary buttons displayed using the same colour as the CTA's used to control the screen (Previous and Done). I would find a different way of presenting that information if it is needed.
I agree, there is no clarity about what font size has been selected. that either needs to be provided by the slider or somehow by the core font in the box.
The drop down and the slider are both common controls so not sure you are looking for feedback on those.